# sed replace multiple blank lines with single blank line

Tags: regex, sed, blank-line

I have written a sed script, which replaces multiple blank lines with a single one, but it is not working as supposed to. I will be thankful to everybody, who can explain me why. Please do not refer me to working examples, I am familiar with Google. I just want to understand how sed works.

The code is

```
sed ':a;/^\n*$/{N;ba};s/^\n\n*/\n/' input_file
```

so the logic is simple: when sed reads the line and it is either blank or has several newline symbols (this is `/^*\n$` condition), I tell sed to append the next line to pattern space. as soon as a non-blank line is found, the substitution `s/^\n\n*/\n/` is done.

Everything works fine except the cases when I have blank lines in the end of the file. These blanks are not replaced with a single blank and I do not understand why.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is `sed` getting `EOF` while reading next line.

Your command is getting completed at the time of reading next line using `N`. Because, While reading the next line, `sed` getting `EOF` . So, It won't process `s/^\n\n*/\n/` substitution. That is why, You are not able to remove sequence of empty lines which has appeared in end of file.

My solution is:

```
sed ':a; /^\n*$/{ s/\n//; N;  ba};' yourfile
```

Comment: can you explain the syntax

Comment: also i found another answer `sed -i '/^$/d;G' DjangoDocumentaion.md` which `Delete blank lines and insert one blank line after each line`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `\n\n*`, you could use `\n+`

By the way, this is what it would look like as a Perl one-liner:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\n+/\n/g' yourfile
```

Or, for the same result but fewer substitutions:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\n\n+/\n/g' yourfile
```

Or, even more magical, try this compact solution suggested by @hwnd:

```
perl -00 -pe ''
```

Comment: op wants to replace all the consecutive blanklines with a single blank line. You command removes all the blank lines.

Comment: this does not address the issue, newlines at the end of the file will still be ignored if you use `\n+`. Plus, OP specified he wanted to work with sed

Comment: @zx81 If you want to remove consecutive blank lines, use `perl -00 -pe ''`